# Interstitial ad implementation error in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, ads, interstitial

[image]

Here I am trying to initialize Interstitial ad in my app but whenever I am trying to initialize it shows " Can't create an object for abstract class ". I have imported 'import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd'. I don't know what's wrong here. Please help to find it out.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial#kotlin), the following code is recommended:

```
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAdLoadCallback;


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  private var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd? = null
  private final var TAG = 'MainActivity'
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

      var adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()

      InterstitialAd.load(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest, object : InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
        override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
          Log.d(TAG, adError?.message)
          mInterstitialAd = null
        }

        override fun onAdLoaded(interstitialAd: InterstitialAd) {
          Log.d(TAG, 'Ad was loaded.')
          mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd
        }
      })
    }
}
```

Now to show ad, use the following code:

```
if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
        mInterstitialAd?.show(this)
} else {
   Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.")
}
```

Comment: Do we need to use show() method as well after initialising it? As I can see above there is nothing for showing the ad after initialisation?

Comment: Kindly mark the answer as correct and upvote it so other needy could find it easily.